# Isomorphism between vector spaces concerning kernel of a continuous application

Tags: functional-analysis

How can I prove that if $T:X -> Y$ is continuous, $T_0:X/Z -> Y$ is also continuous, with $Z=Ker(T)$? Also, why $||T||=||T_0||$? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

$T_0(x+Z)=T(x)$. This is a well defined linear map. If $x+Z_n \to x+Z$ in $X|Z$ then there exists a sequence $\{z_n\}$ in $Z$ such that $x_n+z_n \to x+z$. [This follows from the definition of norm in the quotient space]. Since $T$ is continuous we get $T(x_n+z_n) \to T(x+z)$ and hence $T(x_n) \to Tx$. Thus $T_0$ is continuous. Note that $\|T_0(x+Z)\|=\|Tx\|=\|T(x+z)\| \leq \|T\|\|x+z\|$ for all $z \in Z$. taking inf over $z$ we get $\|T_0\| \leq \|T\|$. Finally, given $\epsilon >0$ choose $x$ such that $\|x\| \leq 1$ and $\|Tx\| >\|T\|-\epsilon$. We have $\|T_0(x+Z)\|= \|Tx\| >\|T\|-\epsilon$ and $\|x+Z\| \leq \|x\| \leq 1$. Hence $\|T_0\| \geq \|T\|$.

Comment: Thanks. That's all